# Command line log visualization

Tags: logging, command-line, forever

I am running my node app through forever and I save the log file. My problem is that the log is saved in a formatted manner. So colors end everything is saved. If I `cat` the code to the command line it looks nice but if I open it in any text editor I get the formatting strings as well.

```
^[[0;36mMongoose:^[[0m games.find({ progress: ^[[32m'waiting'^[[39m }) { fields: { _id: ^[[33m1^[[39m } }
```

What kind of format is this? And how can I visualize it properly in `vim` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing ANSI escape sequences.

There's `ansifilter` if you want to translate to plain text (strip escapes), HTML and some other (IIRC) formats.

There appears to be a Vim Script that appears to attempt something sensible with ANSI escapes here:

- http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=302

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used `sed` as follows `cat file.name | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" > output.txt`.